# Spring boot: Failed to perform cleanup of multipart items

Tags: spring-boot, iostream, servlet-filters, spring-mvc-test

When I want to transfer a file to spring mvc from browser using http, there will be a error.If I remove the filters, there will be accept.I infer the error occured in filters.And so on, If I delete the temp file in operation system, It will show that the file is occupied when mine program running.
My operation system windows 11, but anthor windows 10 will occur the same problem. Thank you.
**This error message.**

```
Failed to perform cleanup of multipart items

java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8001.441852335346351027\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_ab11a691_98c7_4d25_ad85_1fa9c0b46365_00000000.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:431) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:54) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.cleanupMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.cleanupMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1250) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1107) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at com.ccd.pdq.filter.OAFilter.doFilterInternal(OAFilter.java:98) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at com.ccd.pdq.filter.JwtTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenFilter.java:87) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8001.441852335346351027\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_ab11a691_98c7_4d25_ad85_1fa9c0b46365_00000000.tmp
    ... 106 more

7月 27, 2023 9:11:23 上午 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor service
严重: Error processing request
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8001.441852335346351027\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_ab11a691_98c7_4d25_ad85_1fa9c0b46365_00000000.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.recycle(Request.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:441)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8001.441852335346351027\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_ab11a691_98c7_4d25_ad85_1fa9c0b46365_00000000.tmp
    ... 13 more

7月 27, 2023 9:11:23 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler process
严重: Error reading request, ignored
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8001.441852335346351027\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_ab11a691_98c7_4d25_ad85_1fa9c0b46365_00000000.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.recycle(Request.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.log(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8001.441852335346351027\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_ab11a691_98c7_4d25_ad85_1fa9c0b46365_00000000.tmp
    ... 13 more

7月 27, 2023 9:11:23 上午 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor doRun
严重: Error running socket processor
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8001.441852335346351027\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_ab11a691_98c7_4d25_ad85_1fa9c0b46365_00000000.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.recycle(Request.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.log(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.checkRecycled(CoyoteAdapter.java:539)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.recycle(Http11Processor.java:1439)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release(AbstractProtocol.java:1098)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:1056)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8001.441852335346351027\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_ab11a691_98c7_4d25_ad85_1fa9c0b46365_00000000.tmp
    ... 14 more
```

## **This is my code**:

```
package com.ccd.pdq.filter;

import com.ccd.pdq.dto.ResponseDTO;
import com.ccd.pdq.entity.UserInfo;
import com.ccd.pdq.util.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @Autowired
    private RedisUtil redisUtil;

    public void sendError(HttpServletResponse response, int code, String message) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(code);
        HttpResponseUtil.sendMessage(response, gson.toJson(ResponseDTO.failUnauthorized(message)));
        log.error("error message:{}", message);
    }
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String uri = request.getRequestURI().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
            AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
            if (antPathMatcher.match("/swagger-ui/**", uri) || antPathMatcher.match("/swagger-ui.html", uri) ||
                    antPathMatcher.match("/doc-api/**", uri) || antPathMatcher.match("/**/login", uri) ||
                    antPathMatcher.match("/health", uri) || antPathMatcher.match("/**/share/*", uri) ||
                    antPathMatcher.match("/actuator/health/**", uri) || StringUtil.isImage(uri) ||
                    antPathMatcher.match("/doc.html", uri) || antPathMatcher.match("/**/api-docs/**", uri) ||
                    antPathMatcher.match("/webjars/**", uri) || antPathMatcher.match("/**/register", uri) ||
                    antPathMatcher.match("/api/document-center/v1/tc", uri) || antPathMatcher.match("/favicon.ico", uri) ||
                    antPathMatcher.match("/api/technology-file-type", uri) ||
                    (antPathMatcher.match("/api/" + "/file/*", uri) && AccessUtil.isAccess(request))) {//放行
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

            // 如果没有携带令牌或者令牌不合法
            String header = request.getHeader(JwtUtil.HEADER);
            if (!StringUtils.hasText(header) || !header.startsWith(JwtUtil.PREFIX)) {
                log.info(uri);
                this.sendError(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "not authorized, token dose not exist, please login");
                return ;
            }
            String uuid = JwtUtil.validateToken("uuid", header);
            if (!StringUtils.hasText(uuid)) {
                this.sendError(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "authentication is invalid, uuid dose not contain, please login again");
                return ;
            }
            UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) redisUtil.getKey(uuid);//过期
            if (userInfo == null) {
                this.sendError(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "authentication is invalid, token has expired, please login again");
                return;
            }
            Object uuidOnRedis = redisUtil.getKey(String.valueOf(userInfo.getId()));
            if (uuidOnRedis == null || !uuidOnRedis.equals(uuid)) {
                this.sendError(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "authentication is invalid, please login again");
                return ;
            }
            // 更新redis中的到期时间
            redisUtil.updateKey(uuid);
            redisUtil.updateKey(String.valueOf(userInfo.getId()));

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userInfo, null, userInfo.getAuthorities());//写入user
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);//reset authentication
            chain.doFilter(request, response); // error occured position

        } catch (AuthenticationException | ServletException e) {
            this.sendError(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
package com.ccd.pdq.controller;

import com.ccd.pdq.dto.ResponseDTO;
import com.ccd.pdq.util.currentcad.CadHelper;
import com.ccd.pdq.util.ecm.EcmHelper;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameters;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.ParameterIn;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/ecm")
@Slf4j
public class EcmController {

    @Autowired
    CadHelper cadHelper;


    @Parameter(name = "file", description = "文件", required = true, in = ParameterIn.DEFAULT, ref = "file")
    @PostMapping("/2dimport")
    ResponseDTO<String> upload(@RequestParam("file") @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String s = cadHelper.import2DModel(file);
        return ResponseDTO.success(s);
    }
}
```

I could get the right result.

Comment: I realized this error too when running on windows but when running on Linux(Ubuntu) the error is not there